# How to detect device in smarty in prestashop 1.7 in a TPL file?

Tags: php, if-statement, smarty, responsive, prestashop-1.7

I want the following:

& I understand I have to take the codes from context.php of PrestaShop but I seem to be making an error. A link to getcontext is as follows: (The code to detect mobile device is here)
[https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/develop/classes/Context.php](http:///https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/develop/classes/Context.php)

```
{if isset($products) AND $products}
             {$tabname=rand()+count($products)}
            {if isset($display_mode) && $display_mode == 'carousel'}
                {include file="{$items_owl_carousel_tpl}" items=$products image_size=$image_size}
            {else}
                {if device is MOBILE} /* Correct Code Needed */
                    {include file="{$items_normal_tpl}" items=$products image_size="homepage_default"}
                {else device is NOT MOBILE} /* Correct Code Needed */
                    {include file="{$items_normal_tpl}" items=$products image_size="home_default"}
                {/if}
            {/if}
        {/if}
```

What codes should I enter in the IF condition to make sure it detects mobile and not mobile.

Also is the IF condition written properly, what should I change in this code?

This is .TPL File.

Comment: What **exactly** is not working with the given code? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Usually, PHP itself doesn't know which device is requesting the page, and relying on the **device** itself doesn't make your site responsive

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try with :

```
{if Context::getContext()->isMobile() == 1}
    {if Context::getContext()->getDevice() != 2}
        // TABLETTE
    {else}
        // MOBILE
    {/if}
{else}
    // PC
{/if}
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I strongly advise against making calls to php classes directly in the tpl. I just introduced global variables regarding the device, so from version 9.x you can use :

```
{if $device.is_mobile}
   My mobile logic here
{else if $device.is_tablet}
   My tablet logic here
{/if}
```

You can also use :

```
{if $device.type == 1}
   My mobile logic here
{/if}
```

*but I would not recommend it for a question of readability and maintainability.*

if this is not yet available in your prestashop version you can add it via overrides :

```php
<?php

class FrontController extends FrontControllerCore
{
    protected function assignGeneralPurposeVariables()
    {
        parent::assignGeneralPurposeVariables();

        $this->context->smarty->assign([
            'device' => $this->getTemplateVarDevice(),
        ]);
    }

    protected function getTemplateVarDevice(): array
    {
        return [
            'is_mobile' => $this->context->isMobile(),
            'is_tablet' => $this->context->isTablet(),
            'type' => $this->context->getDevice(),
        ];
    }

}
```

or via the prestashop native hooks for example : `actionFrontControllerSetVariables`

See : https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/pull/34024

Answer (score 0):

In Prestashop 1.7.8.2 it works this -->

```
{assign var="dispositivo" value="desktop"}

{if Context::getContext()->isMobile()}

    {assign var="dispositivo" value="mobile"}

{else if  Context::getContext()->isTablet()}

    {assign var="dispositivo" value="tablet"}

{else}

    {assign var="dispositivo" value="desktop"}

{/if}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).